# Problems with SpriteKit after upgrading to Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, sprite-kit

I've just upgraded to Swift 1.2 and I'm having trouble with my SpriteKit scene. My code below worked before the upgrade.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    let scene:SKScene = GameScene.init(size: skView.bounds.size)
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the line

```
let scene:SKScene = GameScene.init(size: skView.bounds.size)
```

The compiler complains that it expects a member name or constructor call after the type name. When I follow the compiler's instructions I get into a circle of further errors and complaints from the compiler. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code into my Swift 2.1 project and it runs fine.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        let scene:SKScene = GameScene.init(size: skView.bounds.size)
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Philiip, I'll open a new project and test. It could be something else causing the problem. I was getting some strange issues with Xcode last night.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a problem with my GameScene.swit code.